# OSX - Can't compress database files in backup script - permission dennied

Tags: macos, bash, rsync, tar

I'm super green on all this so go easy - my first bit of bash scripting.

**I've made a simple bash script that:**

- Logs in to the webserver
- Transfers website files to our OSX server
- Transfers database dumbs to our OSX server
- Compresses the files using tar on OSX
- Saves a date-named archive to a different directory on OSX
- Removes archives older than 15 days

The script works great except it fails because of permissions errors while making the archive - which all occurs on the OSX server.

How do I give the script permission to compress the files? I use the webserver's root user to transfer the files.

The script is super basic - just a bunch of terminal commands like this:

```
echo "START WEB SERVER BACKUP"
rsync -azrP --delete user@1.2.3.4:/etc/apache2/ ~/Backups/webserver-backups/apache/;
echo "Complete"
echo "Starting transfer of mysql databases"
rsync -azrP --delete user@1.2.3.4:/mysql-backups/ ~/Backups/webserver-backups/mysql/;
echo "Complete"
echo "Starting transfer of website files"
rsync -azrP --delete root@1.2.3.4:/website-vhosts/ ~/Backups/webserver-backups/vhosts/;
echo "Complete"
echo "Compressing files into archive - this may take 5-10 minutes"
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
tar -zcfp ~/Backups/webserver-backups/archives/dev-$DATE.tar.gz ~/Backups/webserver-backups;
echo "Complete"
echo "Removing archives older than 15 days"
find "~/Backups/webserver-backups/archives/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -mtime +15 -exec rm -f {} \;
echo "Complete"
echo "WEB SERVER BACKUP COMPLETE"
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that some file (like dbu_1354246775.sql) can't be read by the user that try to create the tarball.
Remove all the files in ~/Backups/webserver-backups with:

```
sudo find ~/Backups/webserver-backups -type f -delete
```

then in your script replace the **tar -zcfp** command to **tar czf**

and relaunch your script

Answer (score 0):

The `p` option is only for extraction. Try this instead:

`tar -czf`

Comment: Cheers mate, I still get the same errors - here is the output:    tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
tar: dbu_1354246775.sql: could not open file: Permission denied
tar: dbu_1348160584.sql: could not open file: Permission denied